# Why can I still see local modifications after switching branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have a problem with Git for Windows.

I have two branches in one project: `master` and `membership`. The problem is that, when I modify a file in the `membership` branch and switch back to `master`, I still have the modification. The `membership` branch is a local branch.

If I commit when the `master` is the active branch, changes are committed to master. If I push when `membership` is the active branch, a remote branch is created for `membership` (which is what I want).

I have tried switching branches but it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you commit your changes to `membership` before switching to `master`? Otherwise it is expected behavior.

Comment: I'm his associate. The problem is, usually git asks to commit before switching branches. This time it's not asking for some reason.

Comment: @vgSefa I think newer git versions are smart about that in that they don't ask if the checkout does not involve conflicts. It saves you a stash-unstash-bracket around the checkout.

Comment: @vgSefa Ah, that's simple: Git asks, if it cannot preserve those changes while switching branches. (If the affected files are different between the current and new branch.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still see local modifications after switching branches because Git is not malicious. It does not have seemingly-safe commands that secretly destroy your data. The commands that destroy your data are the commands that you might reasonably expect to destroy your data.

If you want to completely get rid of local uncommitted modifications, there's a separate command just for that: `git reset --hard`. To also get rid of uncommitted newly created directories and files, use `git clean -df`.

You can do that before or after you switch branches.

If you *don't* want to get rid of your local uncommitted modifications, if you just don't want them to be part of your new branch, commit or stash them before switching branches.

Comment: Upvoted for the word 'malicious'... And the brilliant explanation.

Comment: I noticed that stashing can cause tracked but uncommitted files to 'disappear'.  Isn't this is a bit dangerous if you forget you have a stash?

Comment: @AndyJ0076 It's no more dangerous than if you forget on which branch you committed them, isn't it? The files are still there, and Git can tell you all available branches, tags and other refs, including stashes.

Comment: yeah, to me it's a feature, enabling me to patch things when I'm in the middle of some work, finish the work, then do something with the patch afterward on another branch.